# How to calcualte P^k for k in 2 3 4 50 100?

Tags: matlab

i'm fairly new to MatLab. I have been given a Transition Matrix P =[1 0.7 0 0 0; 0 0 0.5 0 0; 0 0.3 0 0 0; 0 0 0.5 0 0; 0 0 0 0.4 1]

I'm supposed to calcualte P^k for k in {2,3,4,,50,100}

My code goes like this

```
P = [1 0.7 0 0 0;
0 0 0.5 0 0;
0 0.3 0 0 0;
0 0 0.5 0 0;
0 0 0 0.4 1;]

for k=2:3:4:50:100,
    y=P^k
end
```

how do i get it to pick the numbers 2 3 4 50 and 100?

Comment: Typing `doc for` in MATLAB would have solved your question, I think that is a faster and easier way than asking here... This is what you would have found: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html#buhafti-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are basically two ways of doing this:

```
for k = [2 3 4 50 100]
   y = P^k
end
```

Or you can define a vector and iterate through it:

```
V = [2 3 4 50 100];
for k = V
   y = P^k
end
```

Note that the colon `:` is reserved to a [different purpose](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html).

Comment: There is no difference between these two bits of code. In both cases you define a vector and iterate through it. Whether the vector is assigned to a variable or not is rather irrelevant.

Comment: @CrisLuengo This is true from a conceptual point of view but we have someone that doesn't know the basic syntax and I'm just presenting different  syntaxes: one which is the direct correctionof the OP's code and one that is the next step to learn for him/her. I don't see anything wrong with this.